# Confused about data alignment for double variables

Tags: assembly, x86

I have read that a `double` variable (8 bytes) must be 8 bytes aligned.

Now if I am writing the entire code for my program, then I can make the `double` variables 8 bytes aligned without any problem.

But say that I have the following scenario: I create a function that creates a `double` variable on the stack, and I give this function to someone else to use it in his program. Now when my function is called, my function will have no idea if the `double` variable will be created on an address that is dividable by 8!

Can this problem be solved (note that I do not care about the negligible performance loss from not aligning my `double` variables, but I am just interested in knowing if there is a solution to this problem)?

Comment: AFAIK `gcc` already aligns the stack to 16 bytes, which means that it also fulfills 8-byte alignment requirements.

Comment: @眠りネロク: Depends.on the version of Linux. I can't recall when but prior to about 2009 Linux was still using the historic SysV i386 ABI which only required 4 byte stack alignment. GCC changed this to 16 (breaking with the original ABI) and then the ABI was modified to be 16-byte stack alignment  on a function call. So technically what alignment is in use depends on the version of Linux.

Comment: @MichaelPetch right. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions: ***Since GCC version 4.5**, the stack must be aligned to a 16-byte boundary when calling a function (previous versions only required a 4-byte alignment.)*

Comment: This is a very good question! Seasoned assembly programmers know how to do this, but it's not really obvious. Good of you for thinking about this kind of performance problem!

Answer (score 6):

Inside of a function you can force the stack to be 8-byte aligned by setting to zero the three *least significant bits* of `esp`. This can be achieved by means of the `and` instruction:

```
andl $0xfffffff8, %esp
```

The resulting `esp` will be equal (i.e.: `esp` was already aligned) or lower than the previous one. Since the stack on the x86 architecture grows *downwards*, this results in a *padding* with a size between 0-7 bytes allocated on the stack.

Note that if `esp` was already 8-byte aligned before executing the `and` instruction (i.e.: its three least significant bits were already zero), no padding at all (i.e.: a padding of *0 bytes*) is created on the stack.

---

When leaving the function, the previous saved value of `esp` will be restored if you are using the common function *prologue* and *epilogue*:

```
myFunction:
   //prologue: save the current stack frame
   pushl %ebp
   movl %esp, %ebp 

   andl $0xfffffff8, %esp
   //stack now 8-byte aligned
   //...

   leave //restore the previous stack frame  
   ret
```

This way the previously allocated padding will be now deallocated from the stack.

Comment: Worth pointing out that some calling conventions (like modern revisions of the x86 System V ABI) already require 16B alignment of `%esp` before a `call` (so the args on the stack are aligned, and you can get aligned space for locals with the right choice of offset)